# Rails rspec CSV generator error for array of string in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've got specs for my CSV generator

```
RSpec.describe CsvAdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator do
  include_context 'with admin_user form'
  subject(:csv_file) { described_class.new(start_date, end_date).call }

  it 'creates CSV file with proper value' do
    csv_file
    log_file = CSV.open('app/custom/file.csv')
     expect(log_file.to_a[1]).to match_array(
      CSV.generate_line([
                          admin_log1.created_at,
                          admin_log1.action_type,
                          admin_log1.admin_email,
                          admin_log1.old_data,
                          admin_log1.new_data,
                        ]),
    )
  end
```

With error:

```
   expected collection contained:  ["2019-06-17 16:39:22 +0200,New,orlandoratke@cruickshankmclaughlin.info,\"{\"\"email\"\"=>\"\"courtne...=>\"\"2019-09-16T16:39:22.880+02:00\"\", \"\"other_activities\"\"=>\"\"forbidden websites\"\"}\"\n"]
   actual collection contained:    ["2019-06-17 16:39:22 +0200", "New", "orlandoratke@cruickshankmclaughlin.info", "{\"email\"=>\"courtn... \"last_update\"=>\"2019-09-16T16:39:22.880+02:00\", \"other_activities\"=>\"forbidden websites\"}"]
   the missing elements were:      ["2019-06-17 16:39:22 +0200,New,orlandoratke@cruickshankmclaughlin.info,\"{\"\"email\"\"=>\"\"courtne...=>\"\"2019-09-16T16:39:22.880+02:00\"\", \"\"other_activities\"\"=>\"\"forbidden websites\"\"}\"\n"]
   the extra elements were:        ["2019-06-17 16:39:22 +0200", "New", "orlandoratke@cruickshankmclaughlin.info", "{\"email\"=>\"courtn... \"last_update\"=>\"2019-09-16T16:39:22.880+02:00\", \"other_activities\"=>\"forbidden websites\"}"]
```

So as far I see I've got an array of string instead of just an array. I was trying to handle it with something like this:

```
log_file = CSV.open('app/custom/file.csv').to_a
    expect([log_file[1].join(',')])
```

But without results. I also tried to add `([... admin_log1.new_data,]).first.split(', ')` at the end of expected results but I received an error `NoMethodError: undefined method split' for Mon, 17 Jun 2019 16:14:56 CEST +02:00:Time`

Comment: I don't think you need `CSV.generate_line` as this will create a String from an Array. And CSV.open will give you `Array<Array>`.

Comment: What is `CsvAdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator`? What does the context `'with admin_user form'` contain? What do the contents of `app/custom/file.csv` look like? Please, read up on how to construct a [mre]. These might also be of use: [The SSCCE – Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). In order to debug the code, we need to be able to copy&paste&run it. That is not possible with yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(log_file.to_a[1]).to match_array([
  admin_log1.created_at,
  admin_log1.action_type,
  admin_log1.admin_email,
  admin_log1.old_data,
  admin_log1.new_data])
```

`log_file` will be something like `[['a', 'b', 'b'], [...], ...]`.

By using `CSV.generate_row` you are converting the `Array` back to a `String`.

I don't suggest doing this but if you where just reading the file instead of parsing it you could use `generate_line` to create a String and compare it, as such:

```
 csv = File.read('...')
   .each_line
   .drop(1) # remove header row

 expect(csv[0]).to eq(CSV.generate_line([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Now I've got an error: `NoMethodError:undefined method generate_row' for CSV:Class Did you mean?  generate`. I've edited my question, maybe my implementation is not good, could you take a look?

Comment: @mr_muscle I've updated the answer. That last code block should use `generate_line`. Note that this answer offers two solutions to your problem though.

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes unfortunately both are not work, please take a look of my implementation

Comment: @mr_muscle don't add comments regarding an answer to your question, add them here. You'll need to output `log_file[1]` and see what it actually is and maybe just set a var called `row` and compare that against you expected output to see why it is failing. Maybe it is correctly failing?

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to set a var because this data comes from FactoryBot with Faker. I think the issue is in one character `/` but I don't why.

Comment: Do `puts log_file[1]`